# Continue assigning persons list to the next sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a excel file with 5 sheets:

1. Main Sheet
2. PRP Sharepoint
3. SAP
4. FO
5. BO

In the Main sheet, I have a list of persons starting from `F12` cell:

[image]

What the code below do is to copy these persons to column "A" of other sheets depending on the number of rows in their "B" column.

What I wanted it to do:

After assigning of persons for each item in "PRP sharepoint" sheet, it will then proceed to the next sheet which is "SAP", provided the sequence of the assignee going to the next sheet should start depending on who is the next person after the last one on the previous sheet, instead of restarting from the first person once again.

I want to start loop from "PRP Sharepoint" sheet up to "BO" sheet while maintaining the sequence of persons.

```
Sub Assign()

Dim WS As Worksheet
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim Main As Worksheet
Set Main = Sheets("Main")
Dim SrchRng As Range, cel As Range


For Each WS In Worksheets

LastRow = WS.Range("B" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

 ALR = Main.Range(Main.Range("F12"), Main.Range("F" & Main.Rows.Count).End(xlUp)).Count

 For x = 2 To LastRow
 For A = 2 To ALR + 1

    If x = LastRow + 1 Then GoTo z

    WS.Cells(x, 1).value = Main.Cells(A + 10, 6).value

 x = x + 1

 Next A

 x = x - 1

 Next x

 z:

'Do nothing

Next WS


MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

How can I alter the code that can meet what I need?

**UPDATE 2:**

In the Main sheet, I have added a new column G which contains CWID (ID for each person).

[image]

The code in the answer works perfectly but since I have added a new column in main sheet, now I have to adjust the code to work with the "SAP" Sheet

[image]

**Question:**

How would I adjust the code to meet the requirement below

In "SAP" there is a column (Created by) which also contains CWID same with the new column G in main sheet. Whenever the CWID in main sheet is the same with the row in "SAP" sheet, it will not assign that processor to that assignment while still continuing the sequence of assigning.

So if it matches, it will skip it while it fills the row.

Basically, by basing on the (Created by) column in "SAP" Sheet, the person should not be assigned to the item created by him/her.

Comment: Sorry but first of all I have to say that it is almost impossible to understand what you are doing. You need to ask a more specific question. People usually come here with **specific** problems in their code. You will need to break down your question to a specific and easily understandable example where we can see at least the difference of what your code does and what it should do. For general code questions you won't get any good answer here.

Comment: Hi thanks for the suggestion. I will edit the description and provide screenshot.

Comment: Good idea to add screenshots but your question isn't more clear now it only became longer. Nobody reads something longer than one page. You definitely have to work out (on an example not on your actual work) where your issue is. I give you an example: You gave us the construction plan of a rocket and asked how you can fly to the moon. But the real problem was how to get the rocket fuel into the rocket. Find out what your problem is and ask a specific question to get one step further don't try to solve the hole rocket moon flight at once.

Comment: Hi I have edited the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have access to pc right now, i'll try to give probable changes you need for your new request about "Created by" column in SAP

```
Sub Assign()

Dim Main As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet
Dim PersonFirstRow As Long, PersonLastRow As Long, PersonRow As Long
Dim WSLastRow As Long, r As Long
Dim iWorksheet As Integer

Set Main = Sheets("Main")

PersonFirstRow = 12 'row of F12

PersonLastRow = Main.Cells(Main.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
PersonRow = PersonFirstRow 'current row in Main sheet
Dim SN As String, sameCWID As Boolean

For iWorksheet = 2 To Worksheets.Count 'start from sheet2
    Set WS = Worksheets(iWorksheet)
    SN = WS.Name

    WSLastRow = WS.Range("B" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column B of this sheet

    For r = 2 To WSLastRow 'loop through rows of this sheet

        If Trim(WS.Cells(r, "A").Value) = "" Then 'skip this cell if it has already some value

                sameCWID = False
                If SN="SAP" Then If WS.Cells(r,"D").Value = Main.Cells(PersonRow,"G") Then sameCWID=True

                If sameCWID Then 'dont choose this person
                    r = r-1 ' stay at this row to set by next person
                Else
                    WS.Cells(r, "A").Value = Main.Cells(PersonRow, "F") 'F12, F13, ...
                End If

            PersonRow = PersonRow + 1
            If PersonRow > PersonLastRow Then PersonRow = PersonFirstRow 'reset back to first row when we reach the last person

        End If

    Next r

Next iWorksheet

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Please check this for changes... i'm not sure as i can't check it at pc

Comment: Thank you, S.Serp. I will give it a try later and let you know.

Comment: Hi S.Serp, I have added inserted the new codes and tried to replace a CWID which will match in "SAP" Sheet to check whether it will not assign the person on that assignment. I got not responding. But if I let it just normal and nothing matches, it works fine.

Comment: did you test the full code as edited code? i think you did a mistake during inserting new changes... i add full code above

Comment: I just inserted the new codes as per update. I will test the full code tomorrow. Thank you S.serp! Will let you know after tresting full code.

Comment: You are right, S.Serp! I did a mistake inserting new changes to the existing code. I tested the code above and it works! Thank you very much for your help! Super! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Update 2:** (skip sheet cells if they has already some value in column "A")

As i understand, you want to continue person names when you go from every sheet to next while filling their column "A". So, you should not use two For-Loops for persons and sheet rows. but you have to use a procedure level variable and reset it to first row only when you reach the last person (not when you switch to next sheet).

Here is the working code:

```
Sub Assign()

Dim Main As Worksheet, WS As Worksheet
Dim PersonFirstRow As Long, PersonLastRow As Long, PersonRow As Long
Dim WSLastRow As Long, r As Long
Dim iWorksheet As Integer

Set Main = Sheets("Main")

PersonFirstRow = 12 'row of F12

PersonLastRow = Main.Cells(Main.Rows.Count, "F").End(xlUp).Row
PersonRow = PersonFirstRow 'current row in Main sheet

For iWorksheet = 2 To Worksheets.Count 'start from second sheet (first sheet is Main)
    Set WS = Worksheets(iWorksheet)
    'WS.Range("A2", "A" & WS.Rows.Count).Clear 'if you want to clear column "A" before fill (if there are more items in it)

    WSLastRow = WS.Range("B" & WS.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column B of this sheet

    For r = 2 To WSLastRow 'loop through rows of this sheet

        If Trim(WS.Cells(r, "A").Value) = "" Then 'skip this cell if it has already some value

            WS.Cells(r, "A").Value = Main.Cells(PersonRow, "F") 'F12, F13, ...

            PersonRow = PersonRow + 1
            If PersonRow > PersonLastRow Then PersonRow = PersonFirstRow 'reset back to first row when we reach the last person

        End If

    Next r

Next iWorksheet

MsgBox "Done"

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for the suggestion, I have edited the question and briefly explained what I need to achieve.

Comment: I tried the code above and inserted my code in the "..." it's working but it seems to be the same with For each Ws in Worksheets. I needed the persons to be continuously assigned to each sheet by not restarting with the first person on the assignees.

Comment: OK, i updated the answer with a complete working code

Comment: This works as what i have described. Thank you so much! One more question, what if there is already a value in a cell in column A, will this over ride? I wanted to not override as sometimes, there is already value in some rows of column A. And still continue the sequence of the persons being assigned to each item.

Comment: It answered everything. :) Thank you so much for the help!

Comment: Hi S.Serp, can I still ask one last question though? It's related to the macro above because there is an additional requirement for the SAP sheet. And I am not sure on how I can achieve it.

Comment: whats your question? can you ask it as new post and inform me its link or you prefer ask it here?

Comment: I guess, I will just update the question here? Because I have added a new column in the main sheet. I will explain it on the update.